# How to use reflected tables with DeclarativeMeta interface?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html

Written in that page, it's possible to get 'Table' object with reflection.

```
messages = Table('messages', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

However, I don't know how to use it in declarative way.

I want to write some codes like

```
s.query(messages).all()
s.add(messages(sender='a', receiver='b', body='hello'))
s.commit()
```

, as if messages is the class defined in declarative way.
I think that there should be a class method which returns what I want.
Does anyone know?

Comment: You can look into [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection with declarative models in a couple ways with just SQLAlchemy. You can pass a `Table` instance to a declarative model using the `__table__` property (as opposed to `__tablename__` which is more usual if you don't already have a `Table` instance.) Or, you can use the [`DeferredReflection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeferredReflection) mixin which handles this for you and is, I think, somewhat more convenient.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
Base = declarative_base()

class Messages(DeferredReflection, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'

engine = create_engine( ... )
DeferredReflection.prepare(engine)

# make session etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I also want to refresh the reflection while the program is running. For example, in case that the schema of table 'messages' changes, the class 'Messages' should be refreshed. To explain why I'm trying to do this for sure, I'm writing python version of phpmyadmin, so I need this kind of function.

Comment: @user3584499 I see you haven't logged in sometime so this is for anyone with a similar goal.  SA wasn't intended to have dynamic/volatile domain models so to emulate phpmyadmin it would be better/saner to inspect each table post change to create your views.